# Чтение CSV в Delphi

Tags: delphi, csv

возникла проблема с корректным чтением из CSV файла, вроде читает нормально но если колонки в которых в самом тексте есть символ ; и тогда столбцы начинают считываться не верно, может кто сталкивался с подобной проблемой? Вот мой код для чтения:

```
procedure TForm1.N2Click(Sender: TObject);

var f: TextFile;
    s1, s2,FileName: string;
    i, j: integer;
    separator:char;
begin

if OpenDialog1.Execute then
  begin
  edit1.Text:=OpenDialog1.FileName;
  FileName:=OpenDialog1.FileName;
  separator:=';';
   i := 0;

 AssignFile (f, FileName);

 Reset(f);

 while not eof(f) do

  begin

   readln (f, s1);

   i := i + 1;

   j := 0;

   while pos(separator, s1)<>0 do

    begin

     s2 := copy(s1,1,pos(separator, s1)-1);

     j := j + 1;

     delete (s1, 1, pos(separator, S1));

     StringGrid1.Cells[j-1, i-1] := s2;

    end;

   if pos (separator, s1)=0 then

    begin

     j := j + 1;

     StringGrid1.Cells[j-1, i-1] := s1;

    end;

   StringGrid1.ColCount := j;

   StringGRid1.RowCount := i+1;

  end;

 CloseFile(f);

  end;
end;

end.
```

csv  формируется верно, в кавычках... но возникла еще проблема, там в некоторых ячейках есть перевод строки... его бы тоже нужно было считать...

решил проблему другим способом, мне по сути просто нужно обработать массив данных из файла не отображая его, загвоздка была именно в считывание данных, так вот сделал чтение из этого файла через ЕксельАПП

```
  ExlApp := CreateOleObject('Excel.Application');
  ExlApp.Visible := false;
  ExlApp.Workbooks.Open(XLSFile);
```

просто читаю данные в массив и дальше уже с ними работаю

Comment: csv сам верно сформирован? текст который содержит разделитель обрамлен кавычками?

Comment: да, csv  формируется верно, в кавычках... но возникла еще проблема, там в некоторых ячейках есть перевод строки... его бы тоже нужно было считать...

Comment: [Delphi CSV File and String Reader Classes](https://www.codeproject.com/Tips/783493/%2FTips%2F783493%2FDelphi-CSV-File-and-String-Reader-Classes)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте вот так:

```
Var
  inFile : TMemoryStream;
  StrRd  : Boolean;
  CurStr : String;
  Buf    : AnsiChar;
  Col,Row: Integer;
begin
  inFile := TMemoryStream.Create;
  inFile.LoadFromFile('C:/price.csv');
  inFile.Position:=0;
  StrRd :=False;
  Col :=0;
  Row :=0;
  while inFile.Position<>inFile.Size do
  Begin
    inFile.Read(Buf,SizeOf(Buf));
    if(Buf='"') then StrRd:=not StrRd;
    if((Buf=';') and (StrRd=False)) then
    Begin
      StringGrid1.Cells[Col,Row]:=CurStr;
      CurStr:='';
      Col:=Col+1;
    End else
    if((Buf=#13) and (not StrRd)) then
    Begin
      Row:=Row+1;
      StringGrid1.Cells[Col,Row]:=CurStr;
      StringGrid1.RowCount:=StringGrid1.RowCount+1;
      CurStr:='';
      Col:=0;
    End else
      CurStr:=CurStr+Buf;
  End;
End;
```

Сразу предупреждаю - оптимизации ровно ноль, но работает вроде шустро(относительно).
Нормально переваривает переносы строк и ковычки внутри текста обрамленного в кавычки.

ps. не учтена возможность наличия кавычек внутри строк, если таковые будут(верно экранированы) - ничего страшного не произойдет, просто в выходном массиве - их не будет.

Comment: Для учета кавычек внутри кавычек нужен конечный автомат с тремя состояниями, а у вас только два.

Comment: @ГерманБорисов я в курсе, просто предупредил автора вопроса об этом мелком недочете, вспомнил что кавычка экранируется именно так уже после написания кода.

Comment: я это скорее для мимо проходящих, чем для Вас.